# default collection type for SQL nested table type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle type that is a table of numbers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_number AS TABLE OF number;
```

Now I want to use that type in an input parameter in a procedure, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1 (pt_numbers_in IN t_number)...
```

How do I set a default value if the parameter is null?  With a PL/SQL collection type, I know how to create an empty collection (in, say, a package spec) and use that as the default.  Do I have to do the same thing here, or is there a better way to use a default variable of a SQL type?  I want to so something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1 (pt_numbers_in IN t_number DEFAULT NULL)...
```

I'm running 11.2.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I set a default value if the parameter is null?

You'd have to write some code and check if a collection is the `null` collection, and if it is, initialize it.

If by "default" value you mean "I want this parameter to be optional", then simply use `default` clause to initialize a collection like so:

```
create or replace procedure proc1(
  p_numbers_in in t_number default t_number(1,2,3)
)
as
begin
  -- some useful code 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this from [How to Initialize Variables](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/1782.how-to-initialize-variables.aspx)

```
DECLARE
   t_number_var t_number := t_number(5);  -- initialize
BEGIN
   IF t_number_var(1) IS NULL THEN
```